# Django IntegrityError - NOT NULL constraint failed: learning_logs_topic.owner_id

Tags: django, python-3.6

## The Problem

Hi, I'm making a project called "learning_log", where you can make new topics and add entries associated with that specific topic. I have a problem; when I try to add a new topic, an `IntegrityError` pops up on the screen. It keeps highlighting the code: `form.save()` in my `views.py`, after I set up a User authentication and registration system.
This is the traceback I get:

```
    Exception Type: IntegrityError at /new_topic/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: learning_logs_topic.owner_id
```

### The Code

My `views.py` looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def index(request):
    """The Home Page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

@login_required
def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

@login_required
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    # Make sure the Topic belongs to the current user.
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for the particular topic."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                                                args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)

@login_required
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Edit an existing entry."""
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Initial request; pre-fill form with the current entry.
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                                                args=[topic.id]))

    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

My `forms.py` looks like this:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Entry

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

my `models.py` looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        # Add an ellipsis ONLY if the entry,
        # is more than 50 characters long.
        if self.text > self.text[:50]:
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        elif self.text <= self.text[:50]:
            return self.text[:50]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my answer to the problem, that I had.

Django returns an `IntegrityError` because you haven't associated the new topic, with any particular user. It's saying that you can't create a new topic without specifying a value for the topic's `owner` field.
There's a straightforward fix for this problem, because you have access to the current user that's logged in through the `request` object. To fix the problem, I simply save the `new_topic` to a variable, and associates it with the current user logged in, and save the changes to the database.

update for `new_topic()` in `views.py`:

```
@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False) # Save topic in a variable.
            new_topic.owner = request.user # Set topics owner attribute to current user.
            new_topic.save() # Save the changes to the database.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but a bit further they have the answer in the book:

Associating New Topics with the Current UserCurrently, our page for adding new topics is broken, because it doesn’t associate new topics with any particular user. If you try adding a new topic, you’ll see the error message IntegrityError along with learning_logs_topic .user_id may not be NULL. Django’s saying you can’t create a new topic without specifying a value for the topic’s owner field.There’s a straightforward fix for this problem, because we have access to the current user through the request object. Add the following code, which associates the new topic with the current user:
views.py

```
@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            new_topic.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)
```

Answer (score -2):

And for Django 2.2:

```
@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
         # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            new_topic.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topics')

    # Return an empty or invalid form.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)
```